# Windows Crashes 8.1; Won't Start; Files Are Missing from SSD

Tags: windows-8.1

So, I was working on my computer, windows 8.1, when the screen went blue and it said it was crashing. It took a really long time to collect "information", then it crashed.

Upon resetting it, Windows went into the loop of doom, and wouldn't start, instead attempting to (and failing to) recover data.

I booted from a different drive, and checked out the drive that failed. Program files is still there, but my documents and a folder called projects are totally gone!

What happened? Where are they? How can this be avoided?

Comment: It sounds like your SSD partially failed

Comment: It's the partial part I don't understand, why would one folder disappear, but the program files directory is just as expected. Does that not make any sense

Comment: Why it happens is because of how SSDs fail

Answer (score -1):

What caused this? *God only knows.*

Where were my files? They were in `D:/found.000/`

Why didn't they appear in searches?
Because they are encoded as `.chk` files which again no one knows why.

Why is this? No one can guess.

How did I recover them?

Purchase this software for $100 : http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/ad-buynow.htm

Did the job. Found some other free softwares, but given how critical these files were I bit the bullet and bought it.